# Python Selenium multi-threading issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium

I currently have a multi-threaded python script which takes in a bunch of URLS and takes a screenshot of each of them. After each screenshot is taken, I append a timestamp to the screenshot with pillow. I understand that after researching on Google, Selenium is not thread safe. Currently the way I am able to achieve multi-threading is by spawning one driver per URL. This actually is pretty slow and is quite resource intensive.

How can I speed this entire process up? I am willing to drop Selenium and take on a new library if required.

```
def retrieve_and_process_screenshots(url_list=None):

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(multithreaded_screenshot, url_list)
```

```
def multithreaded_screenshot(url_item=None):

    ff_options = Options()

    for ff_option in config.firefox_options_config.split(","):
        ff_options.add_argument(ff_option)

    firefox_driver_path = "..\misc\geckodriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ff_options, executable_path=firefox_driver_path, service_log_path="..\logs\geckodriver.log")

    driver.get(url_item)
    time.sleep(2)

    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime(config.datetime_format)
    image_filename = config.image_filename_format.replace("<DATETIME>", current_datetime)
    image_output = os.path.join(config.image_output_directory, image_filename + ".png")

    saved_screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    driver.quit()

    # Calls this function to do post processing on the image to add a timestamp
    image_timestamp(image_output, saved_screenshot)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're open to switching libraries, I suggest Puppeteer.

A simple screenshotter in Puppeteer with concurrency:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  let url
  while(url = queue.shift()){
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.screenshot({path: new URL(url).host + '.png'})
  }
  await browser.close()
}

const queue = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.amazon.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'https://www.twitter.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.microsoft.com']

; (async () => {
  // 3 concurrent browsers
  await Promise.all([ run(), run(), run() ])
})();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Although I was looking for a different library in Python, I actually don't mind giving JS a go. Thanks for the script.